# Hapi: Port is closed after moving to vps

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I moved my Hapi app from my local computer to a vps and suddenly it stopped working, I checked out and I saw even though Hapi was logging that info Server running at: http://localhost:8080 It was actually closed.

I'm pretty sure it is Hapi problem because other ports are working, I don't have any firewall rules and it is even closed when I port scan my server locally.

This is my Hapi configuration:

```
  const hapiServer = new Hapi.Server({
  cache: {
    engine: require('catbox-redis'),
    host: redisAddress,
    port: redisPort
  }
});

hapiServer.connection({
    host: 127.0.0.1,
    port: 8080
});

hapiServer.register({
  register: yar,
  options: yarOptions
}, function (err) {

  // start your hapiServer after plugin registration
  hapiServer.start(function (err) {
    console.log('info', 'Server running at: ' + hapiServer.info.uri);
  });
});
```

I even changed host to my real ip address and changed port to 3000 but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you catch any err here

```
hapiServer.register({
  register: yar,
  options: yarOptions
}, function (err) {
  // start your hapiServer after plugin registration
  hapiServer.start(function (err) {
    if(err) {
      console.log('registration failed', err) // ???
      return;
    }
    console.log('info', 'Server running at: ' + hapiServer.info.uri);
  });
});
```

Comment: ReplyError
    at parseError (/home/gmbot/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:181:12)
    at JavascriptRedisParser.execute (/home/gmbot/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:480:20)